# SHOW CREATE TABLE in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Does mongodb have some analogue of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in mysql which shows create query for collection? 
Or can I create another collection like existing one with all settings?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. What settings are you referring to?

Comment: @DavidMakogon looks like I had wrong goal and hurried with the question. no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There no analogs for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
But maybe you will find a some usufull functions there https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-administration/

For example the information about indexes you can retrieve with [`getIndexes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) function.
Create the indexes you can via [`createIndexes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndexes/) function.

Example:

```
var indexes = db.collection.getIndexes();
db.collection.createIndexes(indexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MongoDB compass : Visualize, understand, and work with your data through an intuitive GUI.

https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass?_bt=208952627176&_bk=mongodb%20compass&_bm=e&_bn=g&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Americas_US_CorpEntOnly_Brand_Alpha_FM&utm_keyword=mongodb%20compass&utm_device=c&utm_network=g&utm_medium=cpc&utm_creative=208952627176&utm_matchtype=e&_bt=208952627176&_bk=mongodb%20compass&_bm=e&_bn=g&jmp=search&gclid=Cj0KCQiAmITRBRCSARIsAEOZmr6S3Hw_plZO3dbZS7UGwhU2hS-EGz2vB1SR5tAuMOGd-6j82FkQunIaAgDQEALw_wcB

Answer (score -1):

There is no good answer to this question because the schema involved when dealing with schema-less databases like MongoDB is dictated by the application, not the database.

The database will shove in whatever it is given as there is nothing enforcing a consistent document structure within a given collection, even though all access to the database should be controlled through some kind of wrapper. In conclusion, the only place you should look at for the schema is your model classes.